# Local ssh connection slow and unstable

Tags: debian, ubuntu, ssh, networking

I have two laptops on my home network, one connected via WLAN, the other via LAN to the same router.

I frequently connect from one laptop to the other, using SSH, which always worked perfectly fine until recently. The connection is always established from the notebook A, connected via LAN.

Now when I connect from one to the other, the connection suffers from latency to a point where SSH states that the connection has timed out as the second notebook doesn't seem to answer anymore.

The SSH server is a Xubuntu 17.04 and the client is a Debian 8.

I do not understand why this connection has become this laggy, as I didn't change anything from the setup as far as I know.

How could I identify the culprit for these issues and possibly fix the problem?

**edit:** I do use `-x` as I want X11 forwarding, if it matters

Comment: First check: is it an SSH issue or a general network issue - try pinging one host to another (look for packet loss and latency times), try flood pinging (```ping -f```), also try the same to the router from each of the hosts. Another good check for this is start a non-SSH server (web or similar) and transfer a file down, see what sort of transfer speed you get (does it drop, go up, come down, etc). This will hopefully tell you if it's a network (wireless interference, something on the network causing problems, router overload, etc) or SSH (various options) issue to investigate further.

Comment: I've just tried to connect using X11VNC, which streams the desktop fine without any delay.

Comment: Well that certainly points to it being an SSH error (personally I'd still try the ping and a big file exchange to be 100% certain). SSH-specific slowdowns come from a variety of reasons, most commonly some issue with the configuration - have a look at https://serverfault.com/questions/35453/what-can-cause-slow-ssh-session